# Changing variable value based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, data-cleaning

I have data frame:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(1988,1970,1999,2000)
years_practicing<-rep(NA,4)
df<-data.frame("ID"=a, "grad_year"=b, "years_practicing"=years_practicing)
```

that looks like:

```
ID   grad_year    years_practicing
1     1988           NA
2     1970           NA
3     1999           NA
4     2000           NA
```

Now I want to do this (it is pseudocode!):

```
if (ID=1 || ID=2) 
{
   years_practicing[corresponding cell]<-2017-grad_year
}

if (ID=3 || ID=4) 
{
   years_practicing[corresponding cell]<-2018-grad_year
}
```

to achieve this:

```
ID   grad_year    years_practicing
1     1988           29
2     1970           47
3     1999           19
4     2000           18
```

I know how to do it in procedural way (with `while` loop and `if` statements) but I want to do it in vectorized way.

I tried this (and similar variations):

```
year_2017_start<-c(1, 2)
year_2018_start<-c(3,4)
df$years_practicing[any(df$ID == year_2017_start)]<- 2017-df$grad_yr
df$years_practicing[any(df$ID == year_2018_start)]<- 2018-df$grad_yr
```

But receiving error:

```
Error in df$years_practicing[any(df$ID == year_2017_start)] <- 2017 -  : 
  replacement has length zero
> df$years_practicing[any(df$ID == year_2018_start)]<- 2018-df$grad_yr
Error in df$years_practicing[any(df$ID == year_2018_start)] <- 2018 -  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Questions:

1. How to improve my code to make it work. (answer required)
2. Is there a faster way to achieve similar result? (optional)

Comment: df$years_practicing[which(df$ID == year_2017_start)]<- 2017-df$grad_year[which(df$ID == year_2017_start)]   you mistype the `grad_year`

Comment: @Chuan Your code is what I wanted. If you want write answer and I will except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the motivation that you have to use a vectorized approach to update the value; but some vectorized function, such as `ifelse()` may be of a better help here. Anyway, below is the vectorized solution you want:

```
df$years_practicing[which(df$ID == year_2017_start)]<- 2017-df$grad_year[which(df$ID == year_2017_start)]
```

Comment: Thank you. As far as I know, vectorized is better for speed. Can you please also provide `ifelse()` version and explain why it can be better?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a named vector

```
v1 = c(`1` = 2017,
       `2` = 2017,
       `3` = 2018,
       `4` = 2018)

v1[df$ID] - df$grad_year
# 1  2  3  4 
#29 47 19 18
```

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner only uses base R.  If ID is 1 or 2 then the `%in%` expression shown evaluates to TRUE and otherwise it evaluates to FALSE.  These are converted to 1 and 0 respectively when subtracted from 2018 and then we subtract `grad_year` from that.

```
transform(df, years_practicing = 2018 - (ID %in% 1:2) - grad_year)
```

giving:

```
  ID grad_year years_practicing
1  1      1988               29
2  2      1970               47
3  3      1999               19
4  4      2000               18
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(years_practicing = ifelse(ID == 1 | ID == 2,
                                   2017-grad_year,
                                   2018-grad_year))
```

If you have more than two conditions to test (e.g., if you had three years - 2017, 2018, and 2019) you could use case_when:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(years_practicing = case_when(
    ID == 1 | ID == 2 ~ 2017-grad_year,
    ID == 3 ~ 2018-grad_year,
    TRUE ~ 2019-grad_year)
    )
```

## Edit: compare performance of given answers

I was curious about how fast each solution would be. I compared solutions suggested as of August 29, 2019. @Chuan's answer wins! That was fun...

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)

a<-sample(c(1,2,3,4), 20000, replace = TRUE)
b<-sample(c(1988:2015), 20000, replace = TRUE)
years_practicing<-rep(NA, 20000)
df<-data.frame("ID"=a, "grad_year"=b, "years_practicing"=years_practicing)
year_2017_start<-c(1, 2)
year_2018_start<-c(3,4)
v1 = c(`1` = 2017,
       `2` = 2017,
       `3` = 2018,
       `4` = 2018)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  df$years_practicing[which(df$ID == year_2017_start)]<- 2017-df$grad_year[which(df$ID == year_2017_start)], 
  transform(df, years_practicing = 2018 - (ID %in% 1:2) - grad_year),
  df %>% 
    mutate(years_practicing = ifelse(ID == 1 | ID == 2,
                                     2017-grad_year,
                                     2018-grad_year)),
  v1[match(df$ID, names(v1))] - df$grad_year,
  times=500)

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you.